# Facebook Wall Post Using Feed Dialog in cocos2dx & android both

Tags: android, facebook, cocos2d-x

I want to post user's highscore on his/her facebook wall in the game.I have done it in cocos2d using FBConnect.now we are convert game for android also, using cocos2d-x.so now i want same facebook task for cocos2dx & also on android

I have tried Ezisocial plugin for wall post but it run perfectly on iOS not in android.
right now this plugin is also updated by it's developer.so the licence is necessary to use it.
With Ezisocial in android, while i try to run on device it gives error

```
The page you requested cannot be displayed right now.It may be temporarily unavailable,The link  you clicked on may be broken or expired or you may not have permission to view this page
```

How to solve this error?
If anybody has any idea than,i want to know-> Is there any other way to do this task? which run on both iOS and android...
guide me for that....

Comment: check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) link may be it helps you...

Comment: also this a [game example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game)

Comment: I want to integrate facebook in the cocos2dx,the link which you have given is for the starting phase of cocos2dx & android,i have been gone through it.....now i want to post msg on facebook wall which i have mention in my question.

Comment: Have you tried it using ndkHelper?